# How to take remote master branch changes into local develop branch?

Tags: git

I want to take update into my develop branch from master, what I tried to do is applying below commands:

```
 git checkout master
 git pull
 git checkout develop
 git rebase master
```

By executing the above commands I am getting below warning:

**First, rewinding head to replay your work on top of it...**

Also, I am not sure whether I should perform `rebase` or `merge` from master to develop. I referred a couple of articles online and in one it is suggested as

> **Rebases are how changes should pass from the top of hierarchy downwards and merges are how they flow back upwards.**
>   ([Link](https://www.derekgourlay.com/blog/git-when-to-merge-vs-when-to-rebase/))

And in Microsoft [Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/git/tutorial/rebase?view=vsts&tabs=visual-studio) it is suggesting to rebase when(In example its showing rebasing `develop` onto `master`):

> A suggested approach is to allow rebasing local changes that you have
>   made but haven't shared with others, but to merge once you are sharing
>   changes with others. This avoids trouble with rewriting history while
>   still letting you easily catch up with changes as you develop your
>   code locally.

I would like to know the best approach to take the latest changes from `master` branch to develop branch.

Comment: Your `origin/master` branch shouldn't have any changes that aren't in your `origin/develop` branch -- you should be branching off of `develop`, committing to that, and then eventually pushing `develop` to `master`. In such a case, `develop` will never be behind `master`. It sounds like someone is pushing straight to `master`?

Comment: @ObsidianAge Scenario is that we have two teams working on different sprint with same `master` base and both of them have their own `develop` branches. Team A will push any hotfixes directly to `master` and Team B should take those changes from `master` to their `develop` branch before pushing their code to master.

Comment: They should merge if multiple people have clones of the repo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> First, rewinding head to replay your work on top of it...

That is *not* a warning. That's normal output for rebase. If there's a warning, git will tell you so (`WARNING:` like you'd see `CONFLICT:`).

*Note: Fast forward rebases aren't acutally doing any work - no merging, no rewinding of HEADS. So git doesn't output that line, even if you use `git rebase`*

As for choosing between merge and rebase, it's convention in most scenarios. Follow the convention your team wants you to use - if they primarily rebase changes onto master, then do that.

If there's no convention handed down, do as your gut tells you to. Merge preserves order of commits according to time, clearly shows the divergence and then convergence, as it happened in real life. Rebase makes the history look seamless and clean (by editing history, hence why pulled-by-others branches shouldn't be rebased).

I try to use rebase. I like clean history - this person changed ABC, then I changed XYZ on top of it.

Comment: So there's no harm doing rebase onto master from develop and vice versa, right?

Comment: "Harm" depends on whether somebody has pulled that branch/commiit/tag/ref and made commits on it. If someone made commits on `master`, at any client, then you shouldn't `rebase X master` (edit `master`'s history. Note that fast-forward rebases don't edit history). Rebasing onto master `rebase master X` is  fine, because someone can then just pull master with no extra work or conflicts.

Answer (score 2):

In my humble opinion, unless you're a confident git user, `git rebase (-i)`, causes more issues than it solves.

Please note that, for example, neither [GitHub](https://guides.github.com/introduction/flow/) nor [Atlassian](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows/gitflow-workflow) in their git flow tutorials use rebasing.

Of course git flow is just one approach and Atlassian in their [Feature Branch Workflow](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows/feature-branch-workflow) article writes:

> Once Bill is ready to accept the pull request, someone needs to merge the feature into the stable project (this can be done by either Bill or Mary):
>
> ```
> git checkout master
> git pull
> git pull origin marys-feature
> git push
> ```
>
> This process often results in a merge commit. Some developers like this because it’s like a symbolic joining of the feature with the rest of the code base. But, if you’re partial to a linear history, it’s possible to rebase the feature onto the tip of master before executing the merge, resulting in a fast-forward merge.

I'm a merge commit proponent and I would encourage you to not use rebasing.

Comment: Any reason why are you avoiding rebasing?

Comment: @Dishant Rebasing really messes things up if you share your branch with others.

Comment: Thanks. I read this in a couple of blogs but would be better if can give some scenario where things doesn't work as expected with rebasing.

Answer (score 0):

I would avoid rebasing.  If you made some commits directly into master (not a great idea) and need to bring them to develop -

```
git checkout develop
git merge master
```